Which version of Java should I use with Cassandra 5.x
I've installed Cassandra on my Linux machine (Ubutnu).
I had OpenJDK 11 installed, I then installed JDK 17 and set it to the default and restarted Cassandra.

I can see the new version is being used in /var/log/cassandra/system.log

Everything is working but it is unclear to me if using 17 is considered "experimental" or not or preferred to 11?

See this: Cassandra - Support for Java - explains how to use with Java 11 and Java 17.

No, it is not experimental. With Apache Cassandra® 5.0, you are free to use either Java 11 or Java 17.
If it were me, I'd go with Java 17. In fact, I'm pretty sure that all of our (DataStax's) pre-built images for 5.0 use 17, as well.
